# php run command in loop

Tags: php, loops

I want to run specific command 4 times in a loop. How do i do that?

```
$list = array(
"data1", "data2", "data3", "data4", "data5", "data6", "data7", "data8", "data9", "data10", "data11", "data12", "data13", "data14", "data15", "data17"
);

$split_by = 4;
$total_execute = round(count($list)/$split_by);
for($i=0; $i<=count($list); $i++)
{
//1
//2
//3
//4 //execute command 1
//5
//6
//7
//8 //execute command 2
//9
//10
..............

}
```

How can i execute command in every 4 index and total $total_execute time in php?
I have tried but its not working. i have no idea.

Comment: okay edited. could you answer? I mean how do i execute $total_execute execute times only?

Comment: Look at the modulus operator.

Comment: What is `$total_execute` needed for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you only want to process every fourth item in the list, you can construct the loop to do that. (NB the fourth item is index 3).

```
for ($i=3; $i<count($list);$i+=4) {
//command
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The for-loop should be:

```
for($i = $split_by - 1; $i < count($list); $i += $split_by)
{
    for ($j = 0; $j < $total_execute; j++) {
        $elem = $list[$i];
        // Do something with '$elem'...
    }
}
```